# Which is better, Java reflection or extend class in test

Tags: java, junit4

Have a Java class for which, I am trying to write a JUnit test.

Using JaCoCo to monitor code coverage. Hence, need to call private methods as well from test class.

To call main method and private methods from test class using Java reflection.

My question is extending the main class (Example) in test class better or using java reflection to access the private methods? Currently I am using the reflection as below.

Is it even a good practice to extend the Java class in test class?
I am new to writing test class hence, the question. I would appreciate your help on this.

```
public class Example { 
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        method1();
        method2();
        ..........
    }

    private Employee method1(String str) {
        .........
    }

    private Employee method2(String str1) {
        .........
    }
}

public class ExampleTest { 
    @InjectMocks
    Example example;
    .....

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ........
    }
    @Test
    public void testMain() {    
        try {
            String[] addresses = new String[]{};
            Example loadSpy = spy(example);
            loadSpy.main(addresses);            
            assertTrue(Boolean.TRUE);           
        } catch (.. e) {
            .......
        }
        assertTrue(true);
    }
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        try {           
            Method method = example.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("method1", String.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(example, "1111");         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            .....
        } 
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        try {           
            Method method = example.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("method2", String.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(example, "1111");         
         } catch (Exception e) {
            .....
         } 
         assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason that `private` methods need to be called? If the methods need to be used by an external client, even a test case, is it possible that the visibility of the methods should _not_ be `private`? I.e. `protected` or `public`.

Comment: This question is highly opinion based. By in my experience best is to not call private methods, but to design your tests by using public methods only.

Comment: Totally agree with @BojanTrajkovski - the test cases of public methods should cover all the paths hidden in the private methods. If it is not possible, then the code is wrong. If it is hard to achieve - maybe the code is to complicated.

Comment: Thanks, for your responses. It is already existing code. Don't want to refactor much to implements tests. The methods have try/catch to handle exceptions. That code is not covered hence, have to call the private methods. As suggested will make them public instead of using reflection. Thanks, again to all.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use reflection to test *private* methods, it is better to test these methods through the use of the *public* methods.

So in this case use `Example.main()` to test the underlying methods.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would refactor the code to extract `private` methods that need their own testing into new `public` methods in new classes. If a functionality requires a separate test it often qualifies as something `public`.

Other than using reflection, you can change the visibility of these methods to default level and they will be accessible to tests in the same package.

```
public class Example { 

  Employee method1(String str) {
    ...
  }

  Employee method2(String str1) {
    ...
  }

}


public class ExampleTest { 

  @Test
  public void testMethod1() {
    new Example().method1(...);
  }   

}
```